# Loop through array and print HTML dinamcly for each element

Tags: php, html

I am trying to loop through my array which contains objects and print out the data I need into my HTML. This HTML needs to print my first element and afterwards "create" a new HTML showing my second element and so on...

This is my PHP function where I query the DB:

```
public function getCuponesUser(){
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $user = JFactory::getUser()->id;
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM #__cuphoneo_subscripcion as cs LEFT JOIN #__k2_items as k2i ON k2i.id = cs.item_id WHERE cs.user_id='.$user.' GROUP BY cs.item_id';
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $resultado = $db->loadObjectList();

    return $resultado;
}
```

This is what `$resultado` returns: http://pastebin.com/PSX7KMBq

And this is my HTML/PHP code where I am trying to print the data retrieved:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-info">
 <?php  
    $model = $this->getModel();
    $cuponesUsuario[] = $model->getCuponesUser();

    foreach($cuponesUsuario as $valor){
    ?>

 <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapse1">
    <div class="panel-heading-left">
        <h4 class="panel-title accordion-toggle">
            Data 1
        </h4>
     </div>
     <div class="panel-heading-right">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            Data 2
        </h4>
     </div>
</div>
<div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="panel-left">
        <div class="panel-image">
            Data 3
        </div>
        <div class="panel-fecha">
            <span class="label label-info">Data 4</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel-right">
        <div class="panel-desc">
        Data 5
        </div>
        <div class="panel-boton-canjear">
            <input class="btn" type="button" value="Canjear"/>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Where it says Data 1, Data 2, Data 3...etc, is where I need to print out the different values the Query may return.

**EDIT:** Im pretty sure I also have to use a `for` but not very sure how to do this :P

Comment: Have you tried anything? Or just have no idea what may need to go there.

Comment: I tried the foreach but when I use the foreach I have to put the index of the array and I cant do it that was as the array may contain numerous values

Comment: Can you give an example of the desired result based on some example data?

Comment: echoing $valor is not what you want? or $valor['rowname'] ?

Comment: @PatrickQ this is pure HTML example but the way the "accordion effect" repeats itself is what I need to do but dinamcly? http://jsfiddle.net/weaversnap/7FqsX/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$resultado` already represents the array you want to loop over, then this is wrong:

```
$cuponesUsuario[] = $model->getCuponesUser();
```

Just do this:

```
$cuponesUsuario = $model->getCuponesUser();
```

Inside your `foreach` loop, you can access the data like this:

```
<?php echo $valor->title; ?>
```

Comment: If I do it that way and do `echo $valor['rowname']` I get this: `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

Comment: That worked but now I think I need a `for` method to dinamcly create the HTML content properly for each element

Comment: It looks like your HTML is different for each element though, so a `for` loop is pointless...

Comment: Yes but for example: `<div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapse1">` has `#collpase1` for the 1st element and it needs to be `#collapse2` for the second element. It should be I believe `#collapse$i` where $i is the `for` method.

Comment: That's a different question to the one you asked originally. That said... `id="collapse<?php echo $valour->id; ?>"` would work. **You shouldn't do things like that in production though** because people shouldn't be able to discover things like database ids from inspecting your HTML. Using a simple counter would work too: `$i =0; foreach ($result as $row) { echo $i; $i++ }`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your use of this syntax:

```
$cuponesUsuario[] = //...
```

The `$var[]=` syntax appends an object to the array `$var`. Because of this, $cuponesUsario is an array with one element, and that one element is your actual data structure. When you call `foreach()` on the array, it only executes one time because there is only one element in the array.

Instead, remove the [] and just assign your result to `$cuponesUsario` directly, since it is already array data.

Comment: And how could I seperate each element?

Comment: Access the elements of your object by the keys: $valor->id, $valor->fulltext, etc

Comment: That worked but now I think I need a `for` method to dinamcly create the HTML content properly for each element

Comment: You do - `foreach` is your `for` method. Everything in the `foreach` block gets run once per object.

Comment: Yes but for example: `<div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapse1">` has `#collpase1` for the 1st element and it needs to be `#collapse2` for the second element. It should be I believe `#collapse$i` where $i is the `for` method.

Comment: Set `$i=0;` before your foreach. Just inside of the foreach, at the top, `$i++;`. Then, `echo "#collapse$i";` where you need #collapse1, #collapse2, etc